# Retrofit GET запрос с несколькими параметрами

Tags: android, retrofit

У меня JSON объекты находятся в API который заканчивается на `?category=lunch&page=0&count=10`. По `@Query` я вычисляю параметр `category`, а как к нему соединить параметры `page` и `count` никак не пойму. Даже пробовал к category параметру сзади добавить `String` `&page=0&count=10`, но выдает exception(не понимает символы "&" и "=". Прошу подсказать решение проблемы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то так:

```
@GET("/someUrl")
Call<SomeClass> getTasks(@Query("category") String category, @Query("page") String page, @Query("count") String count);
```

Comment: Я должен получать обьекты с /someUrl?category=lunch&page=0&count=10 где я должен задавать/менять значения для "category", "count" и "page", и в зависимости от их значений возвращяемые обьекты меняются

Comment: @user239883 сложно понять что вам нужно, обновил ответ